# download file on server progressbar pecl

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, nginx

I am using nginx upload module (http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html) with this plugin https://github.com/drogus/jquery-upload-progress to upload files on my server successfully with progressbar. here is my form:

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file_1">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Now i wants to use an option to download remote files with progressbar so my form is this:

```
<form id="download" action="/upload/" method="post">
    <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="links"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

So if i give a file i.e http://domain.com/file.zip in links textarea and after hit submit it should display me progressbar for downloading files.

I notice from my first upload method there is some data being generated from a link (http://domain.com/progress?X-Progress-ID=0c1ecb6da3f3ffc3848ceb337541ab1d) like this for files being uploaded but i am not sure if i can use this to show download progressbar:

```
new Object({ 'state' : 'uploading', 'received' : 674808, 'size' : 2028876 } )
```

Thank you for any help.
Best Regards

**EDIT FIX**

Found the solution here, https://gist.github.com/1030450 need to use curl, save the progress in file then call with ajax to get current progress...will post my solution later on :)

Comment: Pretty sure this is impossible because JS doesn't have access to the file system, therefore doesn't know how the download has progressed (or even that there is a download in progress). If you want to do this you will need a download manager build in e.g. Java or Flash that has access to this information. Is the browsers own progress bar not good enough?

Comment: thanks for reply sir, then how come see here one example please http://imgur.com/ , plz click on web upload button and give some image url (http://www.example.com/image.jpg), it will display progress bar as its downloading.. Regards

Comment: Sorry, completely misunderstood the question, I thought you wanted to display a progress bar to a client as the client downloads a file, which is not possible - but what you want to do is possible with some fairly horrible AJAX (there is probably a better way as well) - but it definitely is possible. I am not the best person to answer this though...

Comment: its alright, appreciate for your interest though, Regards... anyone else plz?

Comment: Found the solution here, https://gist.github.com/1030450 need to use curl, saved the progress in file then called with ajax to get current progress... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here, https://gist.github.com/bdunogier/1030450 need to use curl, saved the progress in file then called with ajax to get current progress.